# Dynamically create radar charts in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, charts, radar-chart

I have and endpoint in which I already receive my data correctly, my question is related to the fact that I need to format my data so I can display it in a radar chart.

The radar data format goes like this:

```
[ { rating: "rating_field", dataA: data_value, dataB: data_value }...];
```

But my data is structured like that:

```
reviews: [ {average_rating: 6.3,safety_rating: 6.3,comfort_rating: 7.1 ...} ]
```

So, I thought about doing some manipulation throught forEachs and maps so I could format this data over and end up with something like the first example, just to be clear, I have an array of reviews, and each review would be seen as dataA or dataB(or C...) in the radar chart data structure.

So, does anyone have a better idea or should I stick with forEachs and maps?

Comment: What's the rule for which ratings gets placed in dataA, dataB etc?

Comment: As said, reviews in an array, so each value of a review should be displayed as dataN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need forEach when you have reduce, it makes your code more functional and immutable

```
const api_data = {
  reviews: [
    {average_rating: 6.3,safety_rating: 6.3,comfort_rating: 7.1},
    {average_rating: 6.4,safety_rating: 6.4,comfort_rating: 7.2},
    {average_rating: 7.3,safety_rating: 7.3,comfort_rating: 8.1},
  ]
};

const letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

const format_rating = (reviews) => (rating_name) =>
  reviews.reduce((acc, review, index) =>
    ({...acc,
     [`data${letters[index]}`]: review[rating_name]}),
    {rating: rating_name});

const ratings = ["average_rating", "safety_rating", "comfort_rating"];

const radar_data = ratings.map(format_rating(api_data.reviews));

console.log(radar_data);
```